# angular2-highcharts is not working in angular 11

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I was working with `angular2-highcharts` it was working since angular 8 but found its not working after I upgrade to angular 11

Here is my snippet

```
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts';

@NgModule( {
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [        
        ChartModule.forRoot(
            require( 'highcharts/highstock' ),
            require( 'highcharts/modules/exporting' ),
            require( 'highcharts/indicators/indicators-all' ),
            require( './highcharts/modules/annotations-advanced.src' ),
            require( 'highcharts/modules/price-indicator' ),
            require( 'highcharts/modules/full-screen' ),
            require( 'highcharts/modules/stock-tools' ),
            require( 'highcharts/modules/drag-panes' ),
            require( 'highcharts/modules/boost' )
        ),      
    ]

} )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was also facing same issue I change my framework to `highcharts-angular` its highcharts official wrapper. and also have several download and good review.

Your project was working with Angular8 because that version uses the "View Engine" compiler while Angular11 uses the Ivy compiler. The short answer answer to your question is NO. angular2-highcharts does not support the new "Ivy compiler"

Answer (score 0):

As has already been mentioned angular2-highcharts is no longer supported (please see https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts). I therefore recommend to use [highcharts-angular](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular) as well.

Comment: Thanks. I saw the link but was curious about the version support. I got my answer. Thanks again.